# Pass variable to TemplateView

Tags: python, django

```
# urls.py:  
url(r'^search$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="home/search.html")),
```

How would I pass a variable, such as `{'update_time': update_time}` to a TemplateView.as_view?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/generic-views-migration/#extra-context

Comment: Looks like the only way is to subclass from `TemplateView` and add extra context in `get_context_data` method